# Trigger event not working or suspected passing on index

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

`.full-arrow` is an arrow that selects the next page. `.full-navigation` is a navigation bar, quite simply boxes in a line that change colour when you select them.  The rest of the function isn't on here but you get the general idea.

When I create a trigger event to the function below the first one, it goes through okay but I'm unsure whether it's not picking up the `index()` or whether it's just not working at all.  Weirdly, it works the first time but I think that's because the `same_page` variable is declared as `0` in the beginning.

The reason I'm also doubting whether it's the `index()` not being passed on is because the `alert("foo");` isn't coming up.

```
$(".full-arrow").click(function() {
  $(".full-navigation li:eq(" + same_page+1 + ")").trigger("click");
});

$(".full-navigation li").click(function(event) {
  //alert("foo");
  //alert(same_page);
  same_page = $(this).index();
  if(same_page == $(this).index()) { return false; }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you getting the `same_page` variable from? Try using `parseInt( same_page, 10 )`--I have a hunch it's actually a string.

Comment: `var same_page = 0;` which is outside the `$(document).ready(function() {`